# Angular2 /Ionic2: databinding

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a simple component as follow:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Data} from './data';

@Page({
            selector: "main-page",
            templateUrl: 'build/pages/main/main.html'
})

export class MainPage 
{
    submitted: number;
    model: Array<number>;

    constructor(){
       this.submitted = false;
    }
     model = new Data('50', ['10', '20']);
      onSubmit()
    {
        this.model.households.push('3');
    }

    backToForm()
    {
        this.submitted = false;
    }
}
```

with the following template: 
    
      
        
      
      MainPage

```
<ion-content padding class="getting-started" >

      <h1>Random selection of houses generator</h1>
      <div [hidden]='submitted'>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dataForm="ngForm">
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Number of houses in the village</ion-label>
                <ion-input 
                      type="number"
                      required
                      [(ngModel)]="model.totalhousehold"
                      ngControl = "totalhousehold"
                    ></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button 
                    secondary
                    [disabled]="!dataForm.form.valid"
                    >Generate random selection!</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div [hidden]='!submitted'>
          villages: {{ model.totalhousehold }}

          Array: {{ model.households }}


          <button (click)=backToForm()>
              back to form
          </button>
      </div>

</ion-content>
```

this is my data.ts:

```
export class Data {

    constructor(
        public  totalhousehold:      number,
        public households: Array<number>,
     ) { }
}
```

On each submit I push a value in my "households" array and hide the form. Back to Form display the form. If I modify the form value (totalhouseholds), my Array (households) is displayed correctly. But it I submit again without modifying the value; the displayed array is not updated.
Any idea advice be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `model` should be declared as `Object` instead of having it `Array<number>` as it do have two properties.

Other thing is when you try to do `this.model.households.push('3');` technically it should been throw an error as in  `model.households` is of type `Array<number>`(which will only allow to accept number). Because latest version of Javascript it won't allow to put string in place of `number`(If its typescript then you must have get those error at compile time). I'm wondering how that got worked in first place.

For showing `object` value on HTML, you could use `json` pipe to show it.

```
{{model.households | json}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I re-declared model as an Object and I am now pushing only number in my this.model.households Array!  Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @Raphael_b Glad to hear that it helped.. Thanks :) but does that the only thing you had missed? :p

Comment: actually; I still do not get the issue. I found a way around: instead of trying to display my Array {{ model.households }} I am doing a <div *ngFor='#hh of model.households'>{{ hh }} </div> (which is working fine).

Comment: @Raphael_b if its working with `*ngFor` then it should work with `{{}}` interpolation binding.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Raphael_b I'd say that, you should try `{{model.households | json}}` to print json value on html

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript array<3> means you are creating an array of fixed size (3 items in it). If you want to be able to add item, you should use: number[]

```
model: number[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decalre your model as your class datatype. instead of writing

```
model:Array<number>
```

you should write

```
model:Data;
```

The way to propagate values into model is not correct.
Instead of doing this:

```
model = new Data('50', ['10', '20']);
```

you must do this:

```
var myArray:Array<number> = new Array;
myArray.push(10,20);
model = new Data(50,myArray)
```

Using an Object as suggested by @Pankaj Parkar is also a solution, but I feel you are not using typescript the way it should be used. You should be using specific types where needed instead of abstracting everything to Object.